# Why does "unrar" extract everything fine, except for *.html files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, rar

When I try to extract different archives, files with the extension `*.html` never unpacked. Files with other extensions of the same archives successfully decompressed. Why is this happening?

I have Ubuntu 9.10 and Unrar 0.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

Your version sounds awfully out of date. Are you sure it's so low? Try updating it with

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

Or get the latest Linux version at [this site](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm):

```
wget http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-4.0.b3.tar.gz
```